# How to capture an image with multiple names in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a query where I want to capture an image and store it with multiple names.

I can make use of the camera intents to launch the camera and capture an image. I can have a text edit field to capture text. User can enter multiple names of image in the text field like X1, X2, X3, X4 etc.

For e.g. below code shows how to capture and store the image.

Now How I can associate the image with the multiple values from text field while storing. I can change the value of `imageFileName` to the first value from my text field. However how to save the same image for subsequent values for text fields. Do we have to make multiple copies of the image with same name.

Also what would be the best way to store images in such a scenario. I can store it in SQL Lite or store image path in SQL Lite, but if I store the values from text field in different columns, I am not sure how I can retrieve the image with any of the column.

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Any advise will be much appreciated as I am just a beginner in Android

Comment: save the image to drive as file or database as blob, doesnt matter. now you create a usertable referencing the image. So you can either create a table with user, id. id pointing to the table with id, blob for the image. Or you could make a table like user, string while string points to the image on the sdcard. now you dont have to duplicate the image, you can reference it from multiple users.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBo However Its not users who are referencing the images. Its the values of text box. For example I will have an activity where I will have a button to capture image. Once the user presses the button the camera window will open up and user can capture the image. Once the image is taken the next screen will come where there will be a button like save image and a text box where user will enter multiple name for the image like X1, X2, X3 etc. Now I want to store my image by taking the text from text box and all the CSV Values from text box like X1, X2, X3 should point to same image

Comment: so repalce user with tag, what this basically sounds like. an image having multiple tags. ;)